# Make left float div break inside container (CSS or Javascript)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a sequence of divs that contain fixed width boxes (blue). I would like these container divs to break inside the main page container (white), as the diagram below shows:
[image]
Despite being floated, my code does not allow these container divs to float next to one another or to break inside the container:

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.box_container {
width: auto;
float: left;
background: green;
padding: 10px;
}

.box {
width: 80px;
float: left;
height: 80px;
margin-right: 20px;
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span class="box_container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</span>
<span class="box_container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</span>
<span class="box_container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</span>
</div>
```

If this layout is impossible with pure CSS are there any alternative ways to achieve this?

Comment: the second block container is big so it needs one line alone

Comment: yes, the goal then would be to have the second block break inside the main container.

Comment: you cannot break one element into two. Only inline/text can wrap on multiline

Comment: I don't want to break it into two elements, I want one single element to wrap inside a fixed container.

Comment: *I want one single element to wrap inside* --> this is what I meant by *break into two*. You cannot achieve this with block level element, only an inline element can wrap. (float is a block level element)

Comment: I see thanks for clarifying.. If this layout is impossible with CSS are there alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: it depends on your needs, if it's only a visual layout or you will have content, etc. There is always a solution.

Comment: the containers represent groups of boxes that need to stay inside the same div - that is the only requirement.. there will be content but it should not affect the flow of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate this using a combination of inline/inline-block elements like below but it's more a hack than a robust solution:. By the way, only inline element have the ability to wrap on multiple line.

```css
.container {
  line-height: 120px; /* This */
}

.box_container {
  display: inline;
  background: green;
  border:5px solid yellow;
  margin:0 5px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  line-height:80px; /* add this are important for the hack */
  border-radius:10px;
}
.box_container:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}

.box {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box_container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_container" style="background:red">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can consider `box-decoration-break: clone;`<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break)</sup> and it will be more close to what you want:

```css
.container {
  line-height: 120px; /* This */
}

.box_container {
  display: inline;
  background: green;
  border:5px solid yellow;
  margin:0 5px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  line-height:80px; /* add this are important for the hack */
  border-radius:10px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.box {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box_container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_container" style="background:red">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```